# Update the object value based on array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have 2 object in array

```
dataV[1] = {
            "resolution": "4"
        };

datas[1] = {
     {qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order: "1332"}
}
```

if both index same then i want to update with the value from 1st. I want to update resolution value to 4 from 5. Based on upcoming value from new array value in dataV

Expected output like this :

```
datas[1] = {
     {qty_auth: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order: "1332"}
}
```

Comment: What are the complete values of ``dataV`` and ``datas``?

Comment: dataV is dynamic, Each time resolution value updates based on dropdown value @MajedBadawi

Comment: are they objects or arrays?

Comment: dataV and datas is array, inside that object  something like this `1: {qty_approved: "1", resolution: "4", status: "", order_item_id: "1332"} @Majed Badawi`

Comment: I have posted my question in detail here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808608/update-the-object-based-on-index-and-input-dropdown-change]     So im segregating now part by part for better response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146217/merge-2-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: No. I have to compare and then get the object in array  @HereticMonkey

Comment: All of the answers to that question result in an array..., and all of the answers you've received here are duplicates of answers from that question.

Comment: Yes , its not just merging array, need to check object and then merge based on new value. Its not duplicate of what you mentioned, Please go through the question again. Dont mark it duplicate without checking the complete flow @HereticMonkey

Comment: Don't discount the duplicate without checking whether it answers your question, @ShantalKaula. It's not just merging the array; it's merging the objects in the array. You might need to think for yourself -- the answers might not be copy-paste-able -- but the concepts are essentially transferable.

Comment: Thank you for providing the concept, As i am new here i am looking for some simple solution. maybe you want o provide the concept i appreciate that but its not the duplicate what you shared. thank you again @HereticMonkey

Comment: @ShantalKaula ... From all the comments/answers/approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you're updating the value of `dataV` you can do something like this, to update the `datas`:

```js
datas = datas.map((data, i) => {
  return { ...data, resolution: dataV[i].resolution };
});
```

And if you're using `react` you can do the same thing in `useEffect` with `dataV` as a dependency. So, whenever `dataV` changes, `datas` will change automatically.

Comment: I am using class components , when i try with states each time the value is getting removed, So I am using var in global to process. @Shakirul Hasan

Comment: Then you can try using the process I've written above.

Comment: what if datas array not exist with the particular index ? then how can i check the condition fot it ? @Shakirul Hasan

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [
    {
        resolution: '4',
    },
];

let array2 = [
    { qty_approved: '1', resolution: '5', status: '', order: '1332' },
];

let array3 = array1.map((element, index) => {
    if (typeof array2[index] != 'undefined') {
        return { ...array2[index], ...element};
    }
    return element;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is going to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each item of `datas`. The mapping function nevertheless will be a real function (not an arrow function), thus it is aware of [`map`'s second `thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail) argument which for the OP's use case will be the `dataV` array where one wants to read the `resolution` values from.

The advantage of such an approach is, that one can work with a ***reusable mapper function which is agnostic to outside array references*** because it does process an array while the related/corresponding array gets provided as the mapper functions `this` context.

The mapping functionality itself does try to not mutate the original item reference by loosely decoupling the reference via creating a shallow copy of the entire item. On top the `resolution` value which was read from the corresponding array via `this[idx].resolution` gets assigned to the just created shallow copy.

```js
const datas = [
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order: "1332" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "3", status: "", order: "1331" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "9", status: "", order: "1333" },
];

const dataV = [{
  "resolution": "4",
}, {
  "resolution": "7",
}, {
  "resolution": "1",
}];

// mapping approach.

function copyItemAndAssignSameIndexResolutionFromTargetArray(item, idx) {
  // - this merge pattern is agnostic about an `item`'s structure.
  // - `item` could feature more keys but just `resolution` gets reassigned.
  return Object.assign({}, item, { resolution: this[idx].resolution });
}
console.log(
  'mapped version of changed `dataV` items ...',
  datas.map(copyItemAndAssignSameIndexResolutionFromTargetArray, dataV)
);
console.log('still unmutated `datas` ...', { datas });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the OP wants to mutate each of the `datas` array's items, the above introduced mapper function changes slightly in order to be utilized by a context aware [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) ...

```js
const datas = [
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order: "1332" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "3", status: "", order: "1331" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "9", status: "", order: "1333" },
];

const dataV = [{
  "resolution": "4",
}, {
  "resolution": "7",
}, {
  "resolution": "1",
}];

// mapping approach.

function assignSameIndexResolutionFromTargetArray(item, idx) {
  item.resolution = this[idx].resolution;
  // Object.assign(item, { resolution: this[idx].resolution });
}
datas.forEach(assignSameIndexResolutionFromTargetArray, dataV);

console.log('mutated `datas` array ...', { datas });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Or (desperately guessing)  is the OP looking for a solution where a `datas` item has to be updated/mutated by an explicitly provided `dataV` item? Something like this?..

```js
const datas = [
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "3", status: "", order: "1331" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order: "1332" },
  { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "9", status: "", order: "1333" },
];

const dataV = [{
  "resolution": "1",
}, {
  "resolution": "4",
}, {
  "resolution": "7",
}, ];

function updateResolution(targetArray, sourceArray, resolutionItem) {
  const updateIndex =
    sourceArray.findIndex(item =>
      item.resolution === resolutionItem.resolution
    );
  targetArray[updateIndex].resolution = resolutionItem.resolution;

  return targetArray[updateIndex];
}

console.log(
  'updateResolution(datas, dataV, { resolution: "4"}) ...',
  updateResolution(datas, dataV, { resolution: "4"})
);
console.log('mutated `datas` array ...', { datas });

console.log(
  'updateResolution(datas, dataV, { resolution: "7"}) ...',
  updateResolution(datas, dataV, { resolution: "7"})
);
console.log('mutated `datas` array ...', { datas });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I did not understand this  @Peter

Comment: @ShantalKaula ... done. Explanation, documentation links and 2nd, mutating, approach have been provided.

Comment: @ShantalKaula ... check out the latest tries. And in case of having not found so far the right approach/solution amongst all the provided answers, I suggest to reformulate the entire question where the problem is going to be explained in detail in a comprehensible way, accompanied by a more meaningful example code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can get the corresponding element by array index, you can get the corresponding resolution as easy as the following snippet:

```
datas.forEach( (_, i) => {
    datas[i].resolution = dataV[i].resolution
})
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over `dataV` while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the index is the `key` and the resolution is the `value`
- Using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over `datas`, if the above map has a key of such index, update the resolution

```js
const 
  dataV = [ { "resolution": "4" }, { "resolution": "7" }, { "resolution": "1" } ],
  datas = [
    { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "5", status: "", order: "1332" },
    { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "3", status: "", order: "1331" },
    { qty_approved: "1", resolution: "9", status: "", order: "1333" },
  ];

const indexResolutionMap = dataV.reduce((map, { resolution }, i) =>
  map.set(i, resolution)
, new Map);

datas.forEach((e, i) => {
  const resolution = indexResolutionMap.get(i);
  if(resolution) e.resolution = resolution;
});

console.log(datas);
```